# DotNetNuke evoq Forms and Content Items page not loading?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-9

I've installed DNN 9 evoq 30 day trial and everything's working perfectly, except forms and content items.

[image: here's what it looks like on my screen]

Both the forms and content items page reveals a blank page, other functions are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by enabling permissions of the project folder for the current PC user on top of IIS.

Other issues I've faced were with DNN trying to load libraries that don't exist, this can be fixed by copying the resources out of the project folder. (not sure if it'll work on production, but it's working for my development environment.)

Answer (score 0):

Are they visible in Edit mode?

Have you published them?